# Getting the Name of the Model in a Django template using the Form tag

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I want to Display the name of the model in my generic form template in Django.
I thought about accessing the name via the form template tag. I know that I can easily hand over this information via the context dict - but I want to use the Information from the formclass since I already given the info in the ModelForm's meta.

Is there a way to access this information inside the template?

**Update:**

Since I can not access the value directly I assigned the form a name in the `views.py`:

```
def form_view(request):
    form = Form(request.POST or None)
    form.name = 'Name'
    ...
    render (request, 'generic_form_tempalte.html', {'form':form}
```

and in the template:

```
{% extends '__base.html' %}
<h1 class="page-header">{{form.name}}</h1>
...
```

This works - however it is one step more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. The model is available via `form._meta.model`, but you can't access underscore-prefix attributes in a template, unfortunately.

Comment: Well ok - there are plenty of other options but I hoped I can get away with just writing it once ;)